# AddClass doesnt work - cant define | jquery

Tags: jquery

In my jquery code,

```
$("#hospital-icon-jquery i").addClass("current-icon-yellow");
```

code line doesnt work.

full code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(0)').hide();
} );    

jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="location"]', function(){
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").show(); //show all
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(1)').hide(); //then hide some
  $("#location-icon-jquery i").removeClass( "current-icon-yellow" ).addClass("active-icon-green");
    $("#hospital-icon-jquery i").addClass("current-icon-yellow");
} } ) } );

jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="service"]', function(){
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").show(); //show all
  $(".ea-standard form div.step").not(':eq(2)').hide(); //then hide some
  $("#hospital-icon-jquery i").removeClass( "current-icon-yellow" ).addClass("active-icon-green");
   $("#doctor-icon-jquery i").addClass("current-icon-yellow");
} } ) } );

jQuery(function($){
$( '<div class="container"><div class="row"> <span class="col-md-2" id="location-icon-jquery"> <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt current-icon-yellow"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-2"> <i class="fas fa-hospital cc_cursor" id="hospital-icon-jquery"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-2"> <i class="fas fa-user-md" id="doctor-icon-jquery"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-2"> <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> </span> <span class="col-md-4"> <i class="far fa-calendar-check"></i> </span></div></div>' ).insertBefore( ".ea-standard" );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved.When I must put hospital icon into span, I noticed it was in i.So, need to attention to html code.

it was like this:

```
<span class="col-md-2"> <i class="fas fa-hospital cc_cursor" id="hospital-icon-jquery"></i>
```

now:

```
<span class="col-md-2" id="hospital-icon-jquery"> <i class="fas fa-hospital cc_cursor" ></i>
```